# Save attachment from Gmail to Google Drive AND give it another name

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using Amit Agarwal's fantastic [script to extract attachments from Google Mail](http://www.labnol.org/internet/send-gmail-to-google-drive/21236/) and save them to Google Drive. It saves the attachment under its name and saves the Subject Line of the mail in the "Description" of the file (together with the Message ID).
Instead, I would like to name the file whatever is written in the subject line of the email with the attachment.

An example: The attachment is named abc.pdf, the subject line is "Invoice-February.pdf". As it is, the script would create a file in Google Drive called abc.pdf. Instead, I would like it to name the file "Invoice-February.pdf".

This is the original code:

```
 for (var x=0; x<threads.length; x++) {

var message = threads[x].getMessages()[0];    
var desc   = message.getSubject() + " #" + message.getId();
var att    = message.getAttachments();

for (var z=0; z<att.length; z++) {
  try {        
    if (check) {
      var name = att[z].getName();
      if (name.indexOf(".") != -1) {
        var extn = name.substr(name.lastIndexOf(".")+1).toLowerCase();
        if (valid.indexOf(extn) != -1) {
          file = folder.createFile(att[z]);
          file.setDescription(desc);
        } else {
          Logger.log("Skipping " + name);
        }
      }
    } else {
      file = folder.createFile(att[z]);
      file.setDescription(desc);
    }  
  }
```

The createFile function has no way to add a different name to a blog and I have not found a "renameFile". Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Try with the title as the first parameter https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/docs-list#createFile(String,String)

Comment: @teatimer: Maybe I am reading the doc wrong, but this seems to work only if "content" is a string, not a blob.

Comment: file.setName worked for me: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setnamename file.setName(name)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you take a look at https://github.com/ahochsteger/gmail2gdrive

There is the option to rename attachments under the Config.gs Rules:

//  * filenameFrom (String, optional): The attachment filename that should be renamed when stored in Google Drive
//  * filenameTo (String, optional): The pattern for the new filename of the attachment. You can use '%s' to insert the email subject and date format patterns like 'yyyy' for year, 'MM' for month and 'dd' for day as pattern in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

After this line:

```
      file = folder.createFile(att[z]);
```

add these lines for renaming the created file.

```
      var extn = file.getName().split('.').pop();
      file.rename(message.getSubject() + z + "." + extn);
```

I have added "z" to have unique names in case a message includes multiple attachments.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! 
This code will add the file extension of the oritinal filename to the subject line?

Comment: Seems I was getting excited too quickly. The code does not actually do any renaming. Running the code with or without the two lines gives exactly the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this question is still waiting for answer, but now you can do :

```
file = folder.createFile("the name you want", att[z].copyBlob());
```

Reference : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfilename,-content